# Why doesn't anyone find out the masked man's identity in The Flash

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash

As far as we know, no one (except Zoom) knows the identity of the masked man, even if many characters spent time in the prison with him.

He can't talk, agreed. Yet he can hear and see, and can make noise by hitting the glass and make signs with his hand. It shouldn't be difficult to communicate with him (even if it would certainly be slow), and at least know his name.

Comment: So what is the question? You want us to reveal you the identity of a character which is a secret in the show?

Comment: The Masked Man (aka the Man in the Iron Mask) is Leonardo Di Caprio, the deposed king of France.

Comment: He can hear and see, so that rules out Tommy.

Comment: Logic currently points to Jays father. The skin color and hair in most scenes, the soldiers 5 x 5 knocking code. The daddy issues. But no confirmation. The plot twist will be Earth-2 wally, or a time remnant Barry

Comment: Plot twist no one saw coming. E-3 Flash. Also, his body shape was misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as we know, there have not been very many other people held captive in 
that room with the masked man that could figure it out. (It appears that the people in the Arrowverse have yet to realize that literally everyone is Jay Garrick.)

Wally and Caitlin were unable to communicate with him in the short time they were around him. Barry eventually realized what he was saying, but did not have much time to do anything about it before he had to leave.

Killer Frost *claimed* not to know who he is; she may be telling the truth, since she probably didn't care at that point. But she might also have just been lying, since she seemed to react oddly to Caitlin wanted to let him out. Unfortunately, even if she knew his identity she died before telling anyone.

The only person who was there for very long was Jesse. She may have tried to talk to him, but from the way she talked about him to Barry, most likely she just assumed he was crazy. Given her predicament, she may not have even considered trying to get help from another prisoner.

Zoom himself was also strict about not letting the masked prisoner talk to anyone; he reprimanded him for talking to Barry, and proceeded to beat Barry to a pulp as punishment. So the only time anyone would have had a chance to talk to the masked man was when Zoom was away, and we have no idea how much time he spent away from his lair.

Comment: Upvoting this because of the Season2 finale reveal of the man in the mask... :)